# Draw a direct graph $b=a^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**The question:**

> Given 
>   $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,4,6,8,9\}$, where element $a \in A$ related to element $b \in B$ if and only if $b=a^2$.

How to draw a direct graph of following giving question? I know about draw the graph by giving order $\{\{A,B\}, \{C,D\}, \{E,F\}\}$, but don't know about draw graph using a formula.

Thanks.

Comment: Plot some points and connect them like a parabola : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **directed graph** is a set of vertices where "vertex $a$ maps to vertex $b$" is represented by drawing an arrow pointing from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$.

Here is a sample illustration for the function from $A \rightarrow B$ that you have described:

[image]

Comment: How about the 4 its also in set A right,so the 4 don't need to point to 16?

Comment: i have a question more,

The question gives me a set of relation:

Vertex={A,B,C,D} Edges={{A,B},{A,D},{B,C},{B,D},{C,D}}

It told me for determine the degree and parity for each vertex.

I know about degree is the edges that the vertex connected ,but i don‘t understand about parity ,in my syllabus didn't note down what is it.

Thanks

Comment: @NgTzeSin Cannot point to $16$ because $16 \not\in B$.